# Getting empty result within PHP when in browser I get the JSON exception

Tags: php, json, facebook

I have this code:

```
$url="https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=".$access_token."&fields=id,first_name,last_name&limit=10";
$content=file_get_contents($url);
```

Whenever I use this on a non authenticated user I should get feedback of OAuthException, which doesn't show up in the PHP the $content is empty. While if I copy the URL to the browser I get the result and I see the exception.

I want to detect if the user is logged in and the session data is valid.

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Maybe</strike> Facebook decides whether to respond with exception feedback or with just no response depending on the contents of `Accept` HTTP header(s) you are sending (file_get_contents sends different HTTP headers than your browser).